# Can we distinguish one trackpad scroll in windows from other?

Tags: c++, winapi, msdn, win32gui

I am trying to distinguish one trackpad scroll user action (which translates into multiple mouse wheel events on windows) from the next user action? Is there a way to achieve it like in case of MacOS? I tried the value of lparam and wparams in mousewheel callback, one of these is of course zdelta the other remains same even if there is a significant time difference between two user scrolls(possibly os is distinguishing events)

Highly appreciate the answers.

Comment: "macos" meaning "macros"?

Comment: In this case I think they mean Mac OS. Reads to me like they're looking for something they can do on a Mac.

Comment: Mouse messages are generated by the system for compatibility with programs that predate touch pads/touch screens. If you need to observe input from those input devices, you'll have to use [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input), or [pointer input messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputmsg/messages-and-notifications-portal). Or let the system deal with the low-level input processing and use [Direct Manipulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directmanipulation/direct-manipulation-portal).

Comment: @tadman I have edited the question to reflect correctly. I am looking for answers on Windows and looking for functionality similar to MacOS where we get to know when the scroll started and ended by different phases

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for the response SetContact looks like something I am looking for but I am unable to find some good examples of direct manipulation covering scrolling :(

Comment: If I could simply get that two finger scroll (using laptop trackpad) has started and ended that should be sufficient for me. Direct manipulation seems like a vast area to be explored and I might not have that much time on plate for me.

Comment: If two-finger pan interaction is all you care about, you can simply opt in to [Windows Touch Gesture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/guide-multi-touch-gestures) support.

Comment: @IInspectable problem is touch gesture are only applicable for touch screen devices. My interest is in trackpads in laptops

Comment: If `WM_GESTURE` doesn't work for touch pad digitizers, then your only options are to move lower in the input processing stack. See if you can register for `WM_TOUCH` messages, and if that doesn't work either, you'll need to request Raw Input. If that doesn't deliver the expected input, then maybe your touch pad simply emulates a mouse at the hardware level.